Uneven FWD FX Swap Termination
Is it possible for a Uneven FWD FX Swap trade to be Full Terminated before the maturity?

A termination of a financial derivative usually means designing an upfront amount between two counterparts that eliminates the obligation of any future cashflows on those derivatives. An FX swap has 4 cashflows, 2 in each currency. A termination of an FXSwap would eliminate the obligation to complete all 4 of those (if it was foward starting) or just the remaining two of those cashflows. Is it possible, yes, it just requires the agreement on the upfront amount (or possibly amounts in each currency) by the counterparts.
